# Flow triggered from Apex Test throwing error: DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, failing-tests, duplicate-value, unique-field

**What happened:**
I have a test method calls a method in a class that ultimately inserts a new record for ContactRelation__c object.

**Background:**

- The ContactRelation__c object has a field called "Name" which is an
  auto-number.
- The ContactRelation__c object also has a field called
  "IntegrationId__c" which is a formula field that references "Name"
  field.
- The ContactRelation__c object has another field called
  "ContactRelIntegrationId__c" which is a text field that's set as
  unique and external Id field.

**The problem:**
Insertion of this new record triggered a Flow called "Update ContactRelIntegration Id" (after save on create and edit) which is a simple Flow that copies value of "IntegrationId__c" into "ContactRelIntegrationId__c".

But this step failed with the following error:
`The flow tried to update these records: a2QCo0000004PUZMA2. This error occurred: DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the <a href='https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#'>SOAP API Developer Guide</a>.|FlowRecordUpdate|Set_Integration_Id"`

Attempts to resolve:

1. Deactivate the Flow, **the test passes**. But we don't want to deactivate the Flow.
2. Make ContactRelIntegrationId__c field non-unique, **the test passes**. But we need the field to be unique.
3. Remove "Test.startTest()" and "Test.stopTest()" that surrounded the method call in the test method. The Flow still fails with the same error **but test passes** (for some reason).
4. Deactivated the Flow, added debug statements to inspect the generated "Name" and "IntegrationId__c" field. Checked the environment, no record with duplicate value found.
5. Checked everywhere in the Apex Class, there's no other places that also inserts "ContactRelation__c" record that originated from the same test method. So there's no way it can be duplicated in the same testing context.
6. Researched online but no luck.

Does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Really appreciated if anyone can help!

Thank you for your time on my problem!

Comment: As ContactRelIntegrationId__c field is on same object ContactRelation__c,  flow "Update ContactRelIntegration Id" should be of type fast field update(before save) right? Why did you go for after save flow?  Issue is with duplicate external id i guess but without seeing code we cannot confirm anything

Comment: Thank you @vivekvismayam! Given we're referencing an auto-number, i.e. "Name" field, I'm not sure if the value populates on before save.

Comment: Ohh thats right

Comment: Does this code path work correctly in non-testmethod context?  That is, no duplicate on the external Id?

Comment: Thank you @cropredy, yep it works fine in non-test context. I also tested the scenario with duplicate ContactRelIntegrationId__c exist in org and it failed as expected.

Comment: But I still wonder why it failed in the test context

Comment: what i'd suggest is to reproduce the problem using a minimal use case, including the code-under-test doing the absolute _minimum_ logic and DML to cause the Flow to execute. If that doesn't cause an error in test context then you have a clue.